# How do I add a custom ValueProvider in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

In the old MVC version there is a `ValueProviderFactory`, but in MVC6, I can't find that factory. How could I define custom valueProvider in MVC6?

Answer (score 4):

You can add the factory in the `ConfigureServices` method on your `Startup` class.

```
services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options => {
    options.ValueProviderFactories.Add(new CustomValueProviderFactory());
});
```

Comment: Where is this come from / get resolved?  `CustomValueProviderFactory`  ?

Answer (score 0):

As an updated answer for anyone looking for this in the future: As of .NET 6, in addition to [the answer by @Robert Massa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39328639/3025856), you can configure it using the `AddControllers` extension method:

```cs
services.AddControllers(options => {
    options.ValueProviderFactories.Add(new CustomValueProviderFactory());
});
```